# Google VR SDK for iOS target audience, when to consider Unity API?

Tags: ios, google-vr

When started reading Google VR developer docs, I found that there seemingly exist two API sets for supporting iOS audience

1. [API for iOS](https://developers.google.com/vr/ios/get-started);
2. ["Unity Cardboard on iOS" support](https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/get-started-ios).

Can someone elaborate what's the difference between them? e.g.,if I want to target my VR apps to iOS users, which API set shall I use?

If the above question is too general, let me further ask a more specific one. Say, if my app is just a VR video watching app (think of videos shot by GoPro Omni), will both API sets give me the same result?